# Where can I see log files for failed Docker Desktop Windows installation?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10, docker-desktop

I am trying to install [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) on Windows 10.
The installer triggers the UAC prompt but then nothing else, silently dies.

**Q: Where can I find the log files from Docker Desktop Installation (attempt)?**

(Is there a command line argument I need to pass to *Docker Desktop Installer.exe*?)

---

*Details:*
Windows 10 Pro 64bit: 20H2, virtualization and hyper-v enabled
Docker Desktop: 3.3.3.64133
Context: I used to successfully run Docker Desktop, but an update failed and I could not install or uninstall it. I needed to see the installation log files.

Answer (score 1):

Install logs are automatically generated by *Docker Desktop Installer.exe*, and can be found in:

```
%LocalAppData%\Docker\
```